# MongoDB - unable to setup new DB and user using shell command

Tags: mongodb

In my Ubuntu server, I execute the `mongo` command to enter the shell.

Then I try to setup a new **user** and **db** using below script:

```
 use cool_db
 db.createUser({
 user: 'ian',
 pwd: 'somePassword',
 roles: [{ role: 'readWrite', db:'cool_db'}]
 })
```

When I hit the enter button to execute the command, I am getting below error:

[image]

I am assuming the current user that is running mongo shell does not have enough privileges to do such operation?

if my assumption is correct, how can I give the current user the privilege to execute this command?

Comment: You'll have to login, or get some else to login with the account that does have the privs to be able to do what you're asking. When you login to mongo I presume you're `db.auth()` as a user before `exec` that command?

Comment: this is an aws EC2 server, I login to it via SSH using the private key. I am the only user of this server, and I believe I have the needed privileges.

Comment: Can you confirm id authentication is enabled? maybe provide either your `conf` fiel or `cmd` line args

Answer (score 0):

Before starting `mongod` with authentication enabled you/someone should have created an admin user. If not, then you would need to stop `mongod` and disable authentication. The start `mongod`, create an admin user. You can then restart `mongod` with authentication enabled. Use `db.auth()` to authenticate yourself and then you should be able to add your new user

Mongo doc for reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/